# Android Instrumentation Tests: в папке androidTest/java не удается создать класс

Tags: android, junit

Приветствую, коллеги.
для решения проблемы сделано:
1) build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
   androidTest {
       java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
   }
}
```

2) Run - Edit configuration - + Android Tests - добавлена конфигурация, для которой указаны параметры: All in Module, Specific instrumentation runner (optional) - android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, Target - Emulator.
3) когда в Build Variants выбираю Android Instrumentation Tests, то папка androidTest/java не меняет цвет - не удается добавить тестовый класс.

Укажите, пожалуйста, чтО сделано неверно?
Благодарю!

Comment: Да, и еще сделано - Sync Project with Gradle files

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена после корректировки кода в build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/instrumentTest', 'src/instrumentTest/java', 'src/test/java', 'androidTest/java']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java', 'src/test/java', 'src/test/java/']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}
```